# What is the time period of these chalk/clay layers?

Tags: rocks, fossils, stratigraphy, limestone

These limestone-clay rocks are very common in the Alps, they come from weather changes.

How many years does it take to make one of the rock bands? 7 years, equivalent to an el-nino type event? 1000 years? 20,000 years?

[image]
From the wiki page which is only in French: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formation_marno-calcaire

Comment: upper Jurassic/lower Cretaceous, warm climate, flooded continental shelves, climate cycles from orbital parameters, Milankovic cycles. Here: probably ~40ky, maybe ~20ky.

Answer (score 2):

The layers correspond to thousands of years, i.e. 23,000 years in the Danien timeline: [image]

The page sais that there is a variation of 23,000 for precession of the equinoxes and 100,000 for variation of ellipticity. https://planet-terre.ens-lyon.fr/image-de-la-semaine/Img421-2013-04-15.xml

Comment: here is some background information about how and why the equinoxes changes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession#Axial_precession_(precession_of_the_equinoxes)